# Setting HTML meta elements with knitr

Tags: html, r, knitr, literate-programming

I'm generating HTML reports using knitr, and I'd like to include author and generation date meta tags.

My Rhtml page looks something like this.

```
<html>
<head>
  <meta name="author" content="<!--rinline Sys.getenv('USERNAME') -->">
  <meta name="date" content="<!--rinline as.character(Sys.time()) -->"> 
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Unfortunately, after I `knit("test.Rhtml")`, the HTML that knitr generates is

```
  <meta name="author" content="<code class="knitr inline">RCotton</code>">
  <meta name="date" content="<code class="knitr inline">2013-01-02 14:38:16</code>">
```

which isn't valid HTML.  What I'd really like to generate is something like

```
  <meta name="author" content="RCotton">
  <meta name="date" content="2013-01-02 14:38:16">
```

Can I generate R code that doesn't get a `code` tag wrapping it?  Or is there another way to specify tag attributes (like these content attributes)?

So far my least-worst plan is to manually fix the content with `readLines`/`str_replace`/`writeLines`, but this seems rather kludgy.

Comment: You might also simply `brew` that file.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Another (undocumented) approach is to add `I()` around your inline code to print the characters as is without the `<code>` tag, e.g.

```
<html>
<head>
  <meta name="author" content="<!--rinline I(Sys.getenv('USERNAME')) -->">
  <meta name="date" content="<!--rinline I(as.character(Sys.time())) -->"> 
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I believe the newly added `knit_expand` function would be ideal here. By passing a file through `knit_expand` first and then `knit2html`, you can easily achieve the best of `brew` and `knitr`. Maybe @Yihui can add to this.

Comment: @DieterMenne sure, I'll add to the website; @Ramnath in this case, `<!--rinline -->` is not a bad choice if there are further chunks in the file, and `knit_expand()` will be an additional step before `knit()`

Comment: @yihui Makes sense. But knit_expand provides `brew` like functionality which has been long sought for by Sweave users. One way to reduce the tool chain is to allow users to specify `opts_knit$set(expand = TRUE)` which will run the document through `knit_expand` before knitting it. Alternately, it can be achieved using the document hook, which I think makes more sense since knit_expand can then use data from the parent frame.

Answer (score 4):

Not really nice, but seems to work without adding a hook:

```
<head>
<!--begin.rcode results='asis', echo=FALSE
cat('
  <meta name="author" content="', Sys.getenv('USERNAME'), '"> 
  <meta name="date" content="', as.character(Sys.time()),'-->"> 
',sep="")
end.rcode-->

</head>
```