# Mixing R and LaTeX code in an Rnw file

Tags: r, latex, knitr, ropensci

I'm trying to italicise a scientific name when converting a .Rnw file to a .tex file using knitr. I'm getting an error when running `knit`. This is my code contained within my .Rnw file (needs `taxize` and `stringr` libraries to run):

```
Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum \Sexpr{str_c("Collared Flycatchers (\\textit{", comm2sci(commnames='Collared Flycatcher', db="itis")[[1]], "})")[1]}
```

The output in the .tex file should be:

```
Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum Collared Flycatchers (\textit{Ficedula semitorquata})
```

How can I get this output in the .tex file?

Comment: does http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14124022/setting-html-meta-elements-with-knitr help?

Comment: I would imagine there's an easier way than that, which I haven't quite figured out yet

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works for me

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
<<message=FALSE>>=
library("taxize")
@
Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum \textit{\Sexpr{comm2sci(commnames='Collared Flycatcher', db="itis")[[1]][2]}}
\end{document}
```

Does this give you what you want? Looks right in the output pdf for me.